# Why do I get this watir error in ruby?

Tags: ruby, web, automation, watir

My code is very basic.

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
browser.goto "http://www.google.com"
```

yet the error I get returns :

```
/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1119:in `each': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

In terminal it also says there are errors in a lot of lib/drivers

Comment: First thing to check is that you have both of the gems installed.  And if yes, which version?

Comment: ok, i'm checking now... @alannichols

Comment: how do i check gem versions? @alannichols

Comment: To list local gems, type `gem list` in terminal.  If you've installed the [watir](https://github.com/watir/watir/) meta-gem, use `require 'watir'`.  If you've installed [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver), use `require 'watir-webdriver'`.  There's no need to require both.

Comment: @marriedjane875 did you get this sorted in the end?

Comment: @alannichols watir-webrider is for mac and watir is for pc no need to use both, hat was the only solution that got it to work

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Watir will only drive IE browsers as far as I know so it's use is quite limited.  Watir-webdriver uses webdriver to drive browsers and can therefore work with most modern browsers.  Unless there is a specific reason to do so I'd get watir-webdriver working for your tests.  I've used it on windows and mac and it's worked fine.

Comment: ahhh ok @alannichols that might have been it. I just know when I used watir-webdriver without requiring watir as well, then it worked.